# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'showNotification' of undefined

Tags: angular, google-chrome, push-notification

I want to add browser notification to my app , so I created this function :

```
showNotification() {
    navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration()
    .then( function(reg){

      reg.showNotification('finish button clicked');
    });
  }
```

that I call from here :

```
stop() {
this.showNotification();
}
```

but I get this error :

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'showNotification' of undefined
```

what am I doing wrong ? and is there a better way to make use of browser notification without having any messages from the backend ?

Answer (score 0):

To get registered service worker you must pass scope URL in getRegistraion

Eg:

```
 if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
   
           navigator.serviceWorker.getRegistration('./firebase-cloud-messaging-push-scope').then(function(registration)  {                         
                    setTimeout(() => {
                        registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,  notificationOptions);
                        registration.update();
                    }, 100);
                }).catch(function (err) {
                    console.log("No Service Worker Registered", err);
                })

 }
```